# Possible to have 2 ADSL lines in my configuration?

Tags: networking, router, vmware, adsl

I work from home and have a relatively complicated setup using VMWare ESXi. My kids are using up bandwidth and it's affecting my work connection which isn't good, so I intend to purchase a 2nd line and dedicate that to my workstation. Here's my setup. The Red lines are the intended new bits. Main Desktop PC already exists.

[image]

Do I just have to install a 2nd NIC in my workstation for my 2nd ADSL connection? I want my internet traffic to use the 2nd ADSL line, but still have access to all my home resources. Any tips appreciate before I take the plunge and order it! I'm wondering what routing issues I'm going to run into.

Comment: I'm not a networking expert, but maybe setting QoS rules on the router  to give higher priority to the packets coming from your PC might solve your problem without the need of a second ADSL line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed pfSense in the end with my two lines. Works well.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of options in this situation, it's not difficult to set it up the way you want, although I'm not sure if you would be making the most efficient use of the connectivity. It might be worth looking at some dual WAN routers, many of those can route traffic over one connection (say your VMs and you), and the rest over the other line. It also means simpler networks, and less possibilities of conflicts.

Comment: How would I implement that? I guess I could put another NIC into my Hypervisor and take that from the dual WAN? If it's possible could you draw it? :) I understand pics much better.